# Generate a map image file from tiles and features

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, cartography, tiles, features

I am looking for a way to generate images (e.g. png) from a tile source with features added on top of the map, without user interaction or requiring a browser.

Currently, I am able to create a leaflet map and show features on that map. Now I want to create an image of that map. But I want to create hundreds of different images, so I don't want to use a browser but execute it on a server.

Is there a way to do this? BTW: I don't depend on leaflet, I just need to be able to draw a feature on a map (e.g. POIs or lines).

Answer (score 1):

You should have **plenty** options to achieve what you describe.

It mainly depends on your skills, which software you are comfortable with, etc. I am sure you will find lot of resources here on GIS SE. Look for ggmap, etc.

But for sure Leaflet is not a good option for this use case. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353361/get-the-resulting-url-from-a-leaflet-map-in-r/38364181#38364181

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I've thought that leaflet might not be a good option in this case. ggmap looks interesting. What would be other options? I am a programmer, so the best would be an option that can be easily automated. I want to create the map images in dependence to external parameters and on a user request.